# Elegant way to load an AJAX data to a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have lots of situations in my app where I need to load some data externally.

Do way I do it now is by loading the data via AJAX, returning it to the JS file and then using `$().html()` (or similar) function.

This results into lots of messy html code into the javascript code.

```
$('.articles-container').append("<div class='item article_entree' id='"+ article.article_id +"'><input type='checkbox'></input><div class='title'>"+ article.title +"</div><br class='clear' /><div class='country'>"+ article.country_code +"</div><div class='date'>"+ article.d_published +"</div><br class='clear' /><div class='divider'></div></div>");
```

Like this. I tried loading it externally with $().load() but there are two problems there:

First, I don't know hot to make it so all the information is correctly put on its place.

Second - I am using Laravel and Blade. The jQuery code is in an external file included in the Blade template with `asset` and the paths go all messy. But I suppose this is easier to fix.

Is there any other way to load that html there instead of just pouring it all in every javascript function I need?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I've never tried, but I can't see why you couldn't expose your partial blade templates to a controller, and then load them using `$().load()`. That does mean that somebody could (in theory) navigate to your partial in their browser, but maybe that is not worth worrying about.

Comment: show your ajax code, controller code, html code, this will help us to solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller

```
  public function yourFunction($id) {
    $article = Article::find($id);
    return view('partialview',compact('article'));
  }
```

in partialview.blade.php

```
<div>
    {{$article->id}}
 //your html
</div>
<sript>
 // load your external scirpts here
</script>
```

and in your ajax code

```
$.ajax({

        'url' : 'path/to/yourFunction',
        'type' : 'GET',
        'data' : {
        },
        'success' : function(data) {
             $('.articles-container').html(data);
          },
        'error' : function(request,error)
        {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by writing html code in html template file and js in js file

In Template

```
<div class='item article_entree' id=''>
    <input type='checkbox'></input>
    <div class='title'></div>
    <br class='clear' />
    <div class='country'></div>
    <div class='date'></div>
    <br class='clear' />
    <div class='divider'></div>
</div>
```

In JS Code :

```
$('.article_entree').prop('id', article.article_id);
$('.title').html('id', article.title);
$('.country').html('id', article.country_code);
$('.date').html('id', article.d_published);
```